# In PHP-DI the has() function not working for definition in file

Tags: php, dependency-injection, php-di

Using a php definition file I have created this definition

```
return [
'auth' => \DI\object('MyProject\Users\Handlers\Permissions')->lazy()
];
```

But when I use the has() function to check if the definition exists i.e.

```
$container->has('auth'); //this returns FALSE
```

but the get() function manages to return the object.

```
$container->get('auth') //returns the referenced object
```

EDIT:
The application is a bit complex so cant put all the code here but its meant to bypass an error Im getting when I implement the definitions this way

```
$containerBuilder->addDefinitions([
'auth' => \DI\object('MyProject\Users\Handlers\Permissions')->lazy()
]);
```

The error is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with
>   message 'ContainerBuilder::addDefinitions() parameter must be a string
>   or implement ChainableDefinitionSource, array given

Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: This is not normal indeed, are you sure the config is correctly loaded? Would you mind adding more code (either here or in a GitHub issue) so that I can take a look at it?

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli Have made an edit to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your last edit it seems you are still using PHP-DI 4.

The ability to add arrays was added to version 5.0.0: https://github.com/PHP-DI/PHP-DI/issues/218

Answer (score 0):

And as an addendum, the **has()** function returns a FALSE value if the definition cannot be fully resolved. For example from my example below:

```
$containerBuilder->addDefinitions([
'auth' => \DI\object('MyProject\Users\Handlers\Permissions')->lazy()
]);
```

If the class **MyProject\Users\Handlers\Permissions** is not fully resolved

> $container->has('auth') //this will return a FALSE boolean value

Hope this helps someone